# Where is java3d used?

Tags: java, 3d

The idea of java3d is very interesting, but I don't see any desktop or web applications built using java3d. Where is it used and what perspectives does it have?

Comment: Minecraft would be one good example: http://www.minecraft.net/

Comment: It makes a great final project for your CS class that everyone will love playing at the end of the semester. If you can get around the performance issues, that is.

Comment: How a web application could be built with Java 3D?

Comment: @pimeys: iirc, minecraft is built with lwjgl, not java3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[World Wind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) lets you zoom from satellite altitude into any place on Earth. Leveraging Landsat satellite imagery and Shuttle Radar Topography Mission data, World Wind lets you experience Earth terrain in visually rich 3D, just as if you were really there.
It is very much like Google Earth, but written 100% in Java.